# confusing websocket tls functionality

Tags: c++, ssl, websocket, tls1.2, uwebsockets

ive tried out a websocket library today called uwebsockets.
my code is just the one of the provided examples on their github.

```
int main() {

struct PerSocketData {

};

std::vector<std::thread*> threads(std::thread::hardware_concurrency());

std::transform(threads.begin(), threads.end(), threads.begin(), [](std::thread* t) {
    return new std::thread([]() {

        uWS::SSLApp({
            /* There are example certificates in uWebSockets.js repo */
            .key_file_name = "", 
            .cert_file_name = "", 
            }).ws<PerSocketData>("/*", {
                /* Settings */
                .compression = uWS::SHARED_COMPRESSOR,
                .maxPayloadLength = 16 * 1024,
                .idleTimeout = 30,
                .maxBackpressure = 1 * 1024 * 1024,
                
            /* Handlers */
            .open = [](auto* ws) {

                std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;
            },
            .message = [](auto* ws, std::string_view message, uWS::OpCode opCode) {
                ws->send(message, opCode);
                

            },
            .drain = [](auto* ws) {
                /* Check getBufferedAmount here */
            },
            .ping = [](auto* ws) {

            },
            .pong = [](auto* ws) {

            },
            .close = [](auto* ws, int code, std::string_view message) {

            }
            }).listen(8443, [](auto* token) {
                if (token) {
                    std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " listening on port " << 8443 << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " failed to listen on port 9001" << std::endl;
                }
            }).run();

    });
});

std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), [](std::thread* t) {
    t->join();
});}
```

as you can see i dont supply a key directory or a cert directory, yet running this example on my server (Windows Server 2016 IIS) im able to connect to this in my browser using test sites like https://www.websocket.org/echo.html.

i thought certs are required to even get it to connect yet i get no errors and am able to connect. why is this?
is this some sort of problem on my servers end?

Comment: How one connects to a websocket host is important - Yauheni's answer is probably correct, but knowing whether you're able to connect with a `ws://` or `wss://` is diagnostically useful. It helps to supply the client side of network stuff as well!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you built uWebSockets with SSL support:

```
make -e WITH_OPENSSL=1
```

By default it is built without SSL, and in this case, as far as I can tell, uWS::SSLApp works just like uWS::App. Certificate options are silently ignored.